# How to get all td's spans by clicking outside button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have been read alotof article about each(function(){ ....   to get values html tablee childs. But i can not do that. i would like you help me. My some bad experiments are not working.There is a outside a button which is not in rows. While clicking a button, row values must return me.I need td's span values...

My not working samples:  NOT WORKING:

```
       var id = $("#listsends").closest("tr").find(".label label-warning").text();
```

NOT WORKING :

```
     alert(id);

     $("#listsends").find('.label label-warning').each(function () {
         var textval = $('.label label-warning').text(); // this will be the text of each <td>
         alert(textval);
     });

         var t = $('.label label-warning');
         for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
             alert(t[i].text());
```

By clicking web button(outside of table, not inside) , tables's td ^s span values:

[image]

Comment: What about your html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("#listsends").find('.label label-warning').each(function () {
     var textval = $(this).text(); // as this is the scope of the element
     alert(textval);
 });
```